# Periodically back up ramdisk

Tags: windows, ramdisk

Are there any Windows ramdisk drivers that can periodically back up the ramdisk to a file? I am familiar with ones that can save the file on demand and on shutdown.

I'd like to gain control over the performance/risk tradeoff and for instance set up the system so that it would be unlikely that I would lose more than 5 minutes of work.

(I know I could periodically just sync the files, but performance would probably be better if the ramdisk were backed up into a single-file memory image.)

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 (guessing your OS), just type "backup" in the start cmd. That brings you to the backup wizard to do just that, set up a backup schedule that you configure for either the entire drive or just selected directories. You can pick the backup location and the schedule. The backup file is a zip file that the windows restore can use, or you can peruse it later. The backup location can be on the same machine or a remote pc/server.